# Google In-App-Billing- bad response received

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Could anyone tell me the reason of receiving bad response (error code: -1002) after purchase is finished?

I checked the IABHelper and it seems that the JSONException is thrown due to faulure of parsing purchase data:

```
catch (JSONException e) {
    logError("Failed to parse purchase data.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_BAD_RESPONSE, "Failed to parse purchase data.");

    if (mPurchaseListener != null) mPurchaseListener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
        return true;
}
```

Has anyone of you encountered similar problem? I have set up test billing and it worked just fine.

I have searched for similar problems on SO. I am starting the purchase flow from Activity on Fragment.

Comment: I have now gone through the sample implementation of IAB (TrivialSample) and noticed that I had left developerPayload as empty string. Could it be the reason? What are your best practices on how to generate valid payloads?

Comment: Bartek please see my detailed response here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553515/why-is-it-important-to-set-the-developer-payload-with-in-app-billing/27226646#27226646

Comment: Thank you tomrozb. I will try to implement the "device" variant. But please tell me... could it be the reason of such error (error code : -1002 - BAD RESPONSE). For me it was just a first guess to have the developerPayload unique. Test purchases worked just fine, while I got dozens of real purchases and all of them returned this error code (of course no transactions were recorded).

Comment: I'm using my own implementation similar to the `IabHelper` so I'm not sure if it's empty `developerPayload` or not. The root cause is `JSONException` so  print the exception message to the console and check what's the reason of the exception.

Comment: Problem is solved already. It turned out that activity cannot be launched in singleInstance mode as it causes problems in onActivityResult function (Intent data is always null then). Surprisingly it worked fine for test purchases and failed for real ones!